# Magento1.9 change imprint variables

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

In the backend under System->Configuration->General->Imprint I would like to change the variable "SWIFT" to "BIC".

Is there a way to do that ?

EDIT: screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your screenshot, Imprint seems like your custom extension

Comment: Ok I added some screenshots

Comment: It seems that you are using some custom extension, so I would suggest you search in your `app>code>local` or `app>code>community` directory with "SWIFT" text. After searching I am sure that you will find this text in `system.xml`

Comment: did you find it by searching?

Comment: Yes I did find it thank you! But now I am not really sure how to test it. Because the old "swift" variable is probably deleted

Comment: I have seen the SWIFT was used in the "payment_html" variable, is there a way to edit this and replace swift with bic inside this variable ?

Comment: how to test it means? from your question you need to only do "SWIFT" to "BIC" which I gave you :) If you have different question please post as new question.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will create a new question. You can post your comment as answer I will mark it as solution if you want

Comment: Added as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment and discussion, I am adding answer,

It seems that you are using some custom extension, so I would suggest you search in your `app>code>local` or `app>code>community` directory with "SWIFT" text. After searching I am sure that you will find this text in `system.xml`. If you find it then check if label is translatable or not (I don't have module to I can not check) If yes then you just need to update localization.csv (i.e `en_US.csv`) and need to add `"SWIFT","BIC"`